# How to retrieve an int value from SQL database and compare it with an int value..

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, database

i created a login page, and in its database i crated a column (role) which contains an int value ( 0 or 1 ) to determine the role of the user if it is admin or normal user.. 
so, i want to write a query that retrieve the int value (role) of the login user and compare it with 1 or 0 to redirect the user to its specific page..

this is my code :

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class LogInPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text))
        { Label4.Text = "**Required**"; }
        else
        { Label4.Text = ""; }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text))
        { Label6.Text = "**Required**"; }
        else
        { Label6.Text = ""; }

        if (TextBox1.Text.Count() > 0 && TextBox2.Text.Count() > 0)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Azooz_2\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Gulf_K\App_Data\DatabaseGulf.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select count(*) From Users Where UserName ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password ='" + TextBox2.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            { 
                if (){
                  Response.Redirect("TheArrivalTime.aspx");
                }
               else{Response.Redirect("TheArrival.aspx")}



            }
            else
            {
                Label5.Text = "Wrong UserName or Password !!";
                Label6.Text = " ";
                Label4.Text = " ";
                TextBox1.Text = " ";
                TextBox2.Text = " ";
            }

        }


    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        Label4.Text = " ";
        Label5.Text = " ";
        Label6.Text = " ";
        TextBox1.Text = " ";
        TextBox2.Text = " ";
    }
    protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {this.resetLbls();}
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {this.resetLbls();}



    protected void resetLbls()
    {
        Label4.Text = " ";
        Label5.Text = " ";
        Label6.Text = " ";
    }
    }
```

and i want to put the query in this if statement :

```
 if (){
          Response.Redirect("TheArrivalTime.aspx");
        }
       else{ Response.Redirect("TheArrival.aspx");}
```

so, can anyone help me please ??

Comment: This is clearly not C. At least get the language right.

Comment: #c in Visual studio !

Comment: There is no language "#c" either. You first should learn which language you use, then tag appropriately.

Comment: C# is well known. But you wrote about #c, which does not exist. Maybe you noticed that in programming syntax is essential. And how to tag a question is explained in the [tour].

Answer (score -1):

> why don't select user_type from users where username = variable and
>   password
>   = variable and then put [user type field] in the condition if there is a match
>
> ... count will only give you  a number

Comment: You select count will only give you a number.... but if you select the usertype when there is match of username and password then you are only going to get the user type and be able to identify where you want to go.